# What might be missing in my React project that the CSS stylings aren't getting applied to my components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I am a beginner in React and I am not able to figure out why css is not working in my project. 
I understand that in React we use CSS not directly but it is interpreted and understood as JavaScript only by using webpack and babel.

**What I tried ?**
I thought changing my webpack.config.js file will work, but I am not sure where to make the change and what to change. I have followed some threads in StackOverflow that make changes to load CSS Modules in the project. But I am not sure of implementing that as my webpack.config.js seems to already have css modules by default, the reason I believe is I have react-scripts v3.3, where we have CSS Modules by default.

My react-scripts version - 3.3. 
Also I am using naming convention as ComponentName.css and same while importing that component css file. 
I am not using ComponentName.modules.css file naming. 
I am not sure I am missing some css/bootstrap link refrences in one of project's main files. Please suggest, if we do so somewhere like in Index.js or so. 
Here's my -

***webpack.config.js file :***

```
// "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
                    // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
                    // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
                    // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
                    // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
                    // of CSS.
                    // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
                    {
                      test: cssRegex,
                      exclude: cssModuleRegex,
                      use: getStyleLoaders({
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                      }),
                      // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
                      // containing package claims to have no side effects.
                      // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
                      // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
                      sideEffects: true,
                    },
                    // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
                    // using the extension .module.css
                    {
                      test: cssModuleRegex,
                      use: getStyleLoaders({
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                        modules: {
                          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                        },
                      }),
                    },
```

Comment: Naming the CSS files isn't enough, you also need to import them in your Components: `import './ComponentName.css';` is enough.

Comment: How are you importing your css into your react components?

Comment: I am importing them in my components also. `import classes from './ComponentName.css';` and I am using them as `<div className={classes.Particularclass}></div>`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Dealing with a similar issue now but with Vite instead of Webpack

Answer (score 0):

In webpack.config.js : I made a few changes and also before that I ***removed the node_build folder*** from my project and ran the command ***npm install*** from the terminal.

The changes can be seen here in comparison to the above file : I have ***added the line - modules : true*** and ***removed the line - sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap*** to my webpack.config.js file. Please compare the above snapshot of the file and this answered post snapshot of the file to detect these changes.

**IMPORTANT :** In the few old posts and youtube videos that I found, I saw that : after they were adding the following lines :

```
modules: true,
localIdentName: `[hash:base64:...]`,
```

The parameter localIdentName is now not accepted as the object for the API call that we make through that line. And it thus throws a ValidationError and so removing that line worked for me as my react-scripts version is 3.3 and for someone with react-scripts version 1... that line might still work!

```
// By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
        {
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true //line added here and removed
          }),
          // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
          // containing package claims to have no side effects.
          // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
          // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
          sideEffects: true,
        },
        // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
        // using the extension .module.css
        {
          test: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            modules: {
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            },
          }),
        },
```